# Can not get value of input in reactJS Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to the Typescript and I'm getting error when I'm trying to console.log input field value.
Any suggestions?
Code :

class Register extends Component<{},userState> {

```
state = {
    userList : []
}

emailEl= createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
passwordEl= createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
confirmpasswordEl= createRef<HTMLInputElement>()

registerUser = () => {
    const {userList} = this.state
    const destructList = [...userList]
    // const newUser = [destructList, {
    //     email:this.emailEl.current.value,
    //     password:this.passwordEl.current.value
    //
    // }]
    console.log('--------destructList', this.emailEl.current);

}



render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className={'registerH1'}>Registration</h1>
            <div className="email">
                <input ref={this.emailEl}  type={'email'} placeholder={'Enter your E-mail'} />
            </div>
            <div ref={this.passwordEl} className="password">
                <input type={'password'} placeholder={'Enter your password'} />
            </div>
            <div ref={this.confirmpasswordEl} className="confirmPassword">
                <input type={'password'} placeholder={'Confirm your password'} />
            </div>
            <div id={'buttons'} className="buttons">
                <Link to={'/login'} >
                    <button>Log In</button>
                </Link>
                <button  onClick={() => this.registerUser()}>Registration</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and here is the error :

```
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
```

Comment: Would you mind telling what the error message says?

Comment: You should add all the relevant code like initial component state and the class component using registerUser

Comment: The is the error : "TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'"

Comment: Its a type error... see updated answer

Comment: Well if it says that it might be null then you have to check if it's null or not before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `this.emailEl.current` according to the react documentation. You might also need to guard against null values to make typescript happy.

```js
import * as React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = { userList: [] }
    emailEl = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
    registerUser = () => {
        const { userList } = this.state
        if (this.emailEl.current) {
            console.log('--------', this.emailEl.current.value)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <div></div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a type error, try:

```
emailEl= createRef<HTMLInputElement | null>();

// or
emailEl= createRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
registerUser = () => {
    if (emailEl && emailEl.current) {
       // ts knows value not null
       this.emailEl.current.value;
    }
}
```

See the [docs of `React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref)

Comment: Add minimal working example. Did you assign the ref? Check the docs.